# What connection use emulator in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Android studio has its own settings for connection. There I can use proxy. So this way studio will use that proxy instead of computer wifi connection to sync libraries for example. 
But for example if my application I send requests to the firebase what connection will be used by emulator? It will use studio proxy or it will use computer wifi for that? And if I use real device will it use mobile internet connection or proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested all scenarios. So the answers are the following.

Everything local depends on local WIFI of the laptop. Android studio has opportunity to set up its own proxy but also wount work without wifi. Android emulator has a wifi spot calls AndroidWifi in settings which indicates laptop wifi.

The real device use its own connection. So these are to separate different parts. If there is no connection on laptop but there is on real device. So you can't add library but you can launch based on HTTP requests app on real device.